# Add gap between chart and facet title

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

If you create a chart using the following:

```
ggplot(iris2, aes(x=variable, y=value, color=Species))+
          geom_point()+
          facet_wrap(~Species)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10))
```

Then you get the following image.
[image: Example]

How do I add a space (a white gap, if you will) between where the y-axis ends (its limit) and the facet title?  I've mocked up what I mean below and my desired output.

It's important to note that I've set the limits of y manually in the code, which is how my actual code is set up.

[image: Desired]

I should clarify, I want the y-axis **LINE** to end at 10. The idea is for the facet titles to be "floating" above each of the charts. If I try to add a `hline` that sort of works, but I don't know how to get the y-axis line to end at 10.

Comment: something like this should work `geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = 10, ymax = Inf), fill = "white", colour = "white")`

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to add a white rectangle using `annotate` to mimick the feeling that your facet label are "floating":

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% pivot_longer(-Species) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name, y=value, color=Species))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~Species)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10))+
  annotate(geom = "rect",xmin = -Inf,xmax = Inf, ymin = 10, ymax = Inf, fill = "white")
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Thank you, this is 99% there! My follow-up question -- how would you add a black line across the x and y axis? My issue is that when I do `theme(axis.line = element_line())` the black line runs up past the 10 on the y axis.

Comment: You're welcome ;). Where do you want to add the black line ? What about using `geom_segment` ?